# What should I do to using vendor folder located classes after download via composer?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm confused. Once I download source files into my `/vendor` folder, what do I `have` to do?

I simply cannot follow any instructions that I can search. Should I make a file inside a `vendor` folder? Edit `composer.json` inside my root folder?
Is there something that instruct this madness??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [autoload](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) section of the documentation explains how to use the vendor dependencies.

Simply include the `vendor/autoload.php` file in your PHP script, and you will be able to reference any vendor dependency.

For example:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$log = new Monolog\Logger('name');
$log->pushHandler(new Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler('app.log',     Monolog\Logger::WARNING));
$log->addWarning('Foo');
```

If you're using a framework such as Laravel, you will need to include a `use` statement at the top of each file to use a class in the current namespace.

For an example, see the [Controller.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php) Laravel Github repository.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
```

Comment: The example is great, but just so as not to confuse the op I wanted to reiterate that  `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';` is the key thing here

Comment: Also, you don't _need_ to have a `use` statement. Using such imports just makes it easier to use the classes, traits and interfaces. You can always reference classes with their full FQCN as well.